# using gmail api to sync data from gmail to my app

Tags: android, email

I want to add g mail API and sync data from g mail i.e contact detail,  mail  in my app when i integrate this.i have done main part but i face problem to import com.google.api.client.. 
what kind of library i should add in my project for successfully import this google.api.client all class such as google Credential..
i having error when i import

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;


GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;// here error
    private TextView mOutputText;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS };//gmail scopes have error
```

I have added google play service in my project